# ¿Por qué addKeyListener() ya no espera que presione una tecla?

Tags: java, addkeylistener

Estoy realizando un programa usando MVC y este es mi código.
Cada que el usuario presione una tecla (las que yo vaya a implementar) quiero mostrarlas en pantalla, me las muestra, el detalle es que cuando hago `clic` en un botón de mi calculadora, ya no me permite ingresar caracteres pulsando una tecla. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo?
El código:

```
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   //propiedades de la ventana public java.awt.Label pantalla;//panel donde se mostrara los resultados

   public java.awt.Label pantalla;
   public java.awt.Label pantalla2;
   public javax.swing.JButton[] numericButtons = new javax.swing.JButton[ 10 ]; //botones numericos
   public javax.swing.JButton[] operationButtons = new javax.swing.JButton[ 4 ]; //botones para las   operac Lones
   public javax.swing.JButton borrar, limpiar, resultado, punto;
   private final ImageIcon img;
   //metodos de la ventana private KeyboardEvent key;
   // private KeyboardEvent key;

   public Ventana() { //constructor
      this.setSize( 535, 430 );
      img = new ImageIcon( "C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Calculadora_v01\\src\\Resources\\image.png" );
      this.setIconImage( img.getImage() );
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );//permle que se termine la ejecucion del      programa cuando se cierra la ventana
      this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );//centra la ventana
      this.setVisible( true );//hace visible la ventana this.repaint();
      this.setLayout( null );
      this.setResizable( false );//evita que el usuario camble el tamaño de la pantalla
      //el constructor Inicializa los componentes del programa
      initComponents();//componentes del programa
      this.repaint();
      //    key = new KeyboardEvent( this );
      //    this.addKeyListener( key );
   }

   private void initComponents() {
      //pantalla.setAlignment javax.swing.JLabel RIGHT); 
      this.setTitle( "Calculadora :3" );
      this.getContentPane().setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 98, 117, 120 ) );//establece el color de fondo del 3Frame 
      pantalla = new java.awt.Label();
      pantalla2 = new java.awt.Label();
      pantalla.setAlignment( java.awt.Label.RIGHT ); //alinea el texto del Label a la derecha
      pantalla2.setAlignment( java.awt.Label.RIGHT );//altea el texto del Label à la derecha
      pantalla.setBounds( 20, 10, 480, 25 );
      pantalla2.setBounds( 20, 35, 480, 25 );
      pantalla.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 255, 255, 255 ) );//establece el color de fondo del      Labe L
      pantalla2.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 255, 255, 255 ) );
      pantalla.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );//establece fuente, tipo, y tamaño
      pantalla2.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );//establece fuente,  tipo  , y tamaño

      String num = "0123456789";
      for( int i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ) {
         //Se crean los botones numericos y le asignamos su numero correspondiente 
         numericButtons[ i ] = new javax.swing.JButton( Character.toString( num.charAt( i ) ) );
         numericButtons[ i ].setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );
      }
      //numericButtons[0].add
      punto = new javax.swing.JButton( "." );
      punto.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 40 ) );
      borrar = new javax.swing.JButton( "DEL" );
      borrar.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );
      borrar.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 148, 128, 247 ) );
      limpiar = new javax.swing.JButton( "AC" );
      limpiar.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 148, 128, 247 ) );
      limpiar.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );
      resultado = new javax.swing.JButton( "=" );
      resultado.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );
      String oper = "+-*/";
      for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
         operationButtons[ i ] = new javax.swing.JButton( Character.toString( oper.charAt( i ) ) );
         operationButtons[ i ].setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 25 ) );
      }
      //establecer tamaño de los botones y posicion
      numericButtons[ 7 ].setBounds( 20, 70, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 8 ].setBounds( 120, 70, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 9 ].setBounds( 220, 70, 80, 68 );
      borrar.setBounds( 320, 70, 80, 60 );
      limpiar.setBounds( 420, 70, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 4 ].setBounds( 20, 150, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 5 ].setBounds( 120, 150, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 6 ].setBounds( 220, 150, 80, 60 );
      operationButtons[ 0 ].setBounds( 320, 150, 80, 60 );
      operationButtons[ 1 ].setBounds( 420, 150, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 1 ].setBounds( 20, 230, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 2 ].setBounds( 120, 230, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 3 ].setBounds( 220, 230, 80, 60 );
      operationButtons[ 2 ].setBounds( 320, 230, 80, 60 );
      operationButtons[ 3 ].setBounds( 420, 230, 80, 60 );
      numericButtons[ 0 ].setBounds( 20, 310, 130, 60 );
      punto.setBounds( 170, 310, 130, 60 );
      resultado.setBounds( 320, 310, 180, 60 );
      //agregar elementos a la pantalla
      this.add( pantalla );
      this.add( pantalla2 );
      for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) { //Se añaden los botones
         this.add( numericButtons[ i ] );
      }
      this.add( borrar );
      this.add( limpiar );
      for( int i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ) {
         this.add( operationButtons[ 1 ] );
      }
      this.add( punto );
      this.add( resultado );
   }
}
```

Comment: Quizá porque el foco ya no está en el lugar que "escucha" los eventos

Comment: Hola Ojonegro.sys, podrías mostrarnos la clase Ventana?.

Comment: no me deja poner el código porque tiene muchos caracteres

Comment: Hola, la clase Ventana hereda de ***JFrame***?, porque el ***addKeyListener***, debes colocarselo el.... nota, cuando respondas un comentario, agrega ***@nombreUsuario*** para que este sea notificado de tu respuesta, yo me enteré de casualidad, que habías respondido, por otro lado, no es necesario que agregues toda la clase, solo lo que está relacionado con tu problema.

Comment: @MarcePuente la clase Ventana si hereda de JFrame. ¿Dices que el método addKeyListener() debe estar en la clase Ventana?

Comment: No me refiero a ***donde*** se codifica, sino a ***que*** se le aplica, se debe aplicar al frame de la aplicación, para que siempre detecte las pulsaciones (salvo cuando la aplicación pierda el foco), insisto, necesitamos ver un fragmento de tu clase ***Ventana***, para poder localizar el error.

Comment: @MarcePuente ya he puesto mi código de Ventana en la publicación

Comment: Te sugiero que antes que te lluevan votos negativos, edites tu pregunta y agregues el código como texto.

Comment: intenté agregarlo, pero como expliqué antes, StackOverflow no me dejó hacerlo porque me decía que era mucho más código que la descripción de mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que encontré a mi problema es que perdía el foco. Por ejemplo, en mí método *initComponents()*

```
private void initComponents() {
  //pantalla.setAlignment javax.swing.JLabel RIGHT); 
  this.setTitle( "Calculadora :3" );
  this.getContentPane().setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 98, 117, 120 ) );//establece el color de fondo del 3Frame 
  pantalla = new java.awt.Label();
  pantalla2 = new java.awt.Label();
  pantalla.setAlignment( java.awt.Label.RIGHT ); //alinea el texto del Label a la derecha
  pantalla2.setAlignment( java.awt.Label.RIGHT );//altea el texto del Label à la derecha
  pantalla.setBounds( 20, 10, 480, 25 );
  pantalla2.setBounds( 20, 35, 480, 25 );
  pantalla.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 255, 255, 255 ) );//establece el color de fondo del      Labe L
  pantalla2.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 255, 255, 255 ) );
  pantalla.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );//establece fuente, tipo, y tamaño
  pantalla2.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );//establece fuente,  tipo  , y tamaño

  String num = "0123456789";
  for( int i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ) {
     //Se crean los botones numericos y le asignamos su numero correspondiente 
     numericButtons[ i ] = new javax.swing.JButton( Character.toString( num.charAt( i ) ) );
     
     //desactivo el foco en los botones
     numericButtons[i].setFocousable(false);
     //y así lo hago para todas las objetos de tipo JButton

     numericButtons[ i ].setFont( new java.awt.Font( "arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una modificación, eliminas la clase del *keyListener* y agregas esto** en el constructor de ***Ventana***.

```
public Ventana() { 
    this.setSize( 535, 430 );
    img = new ImageIcon( "C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Calculadora_v01\\src\\Resources\\image.png" );
    this.setIconImage( img.getImage() );
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    this.setVisible( true );
    this.setLayout( null );
    this.setResizable( false );
    initComponents();
    this.repaint();
    addKeyListener( new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {  // **lo que agregamos
        public void keyPressed( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
          // acá llamas al método pertinente
        }
        public void keyReleased( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
         
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: justo hoy pude resolver el problema, desactivé el foco en los botones con 'setFocusable(false);'. De todos modos, gracias por tu sugerencia.

Comment: @Ojonegro.sys, magnífico, podrías publicar tu solución y marcarla como aceptada?, de esa forma tu trabajo puede ayudar a otros.

Comment: lo acabo de hacer  :)

Comment: Gracias maestro!! +1